# Executing an api automatically on AWS Amazon

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was searching about this issue and I did not find anything.
I have a java spring boot application, API, I already uploaded it on EC2 amazon and it is working. But when I close the prompt the app ends. How can I configure it to start automatically on amazon?

Comment: Depends on the operating system. But I'm guessing linux, so basically search about systemd units.

Comment: It is linux, ubuntu

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/919059) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it as a service, as Federico said, or you could run with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#:%7E:text=nohup%20is%20a%20POSIX%20command,has%20not%20already%20been%20redirected.)